# What's the basis for recommending resetting my email password when an unknown account password is compromised?

Tags: passwords

One of the banks that provides identity theft monitoring to accountholders notified me that my email address was included in a recent data breach, along with a password, but without any indication of where this email and password was used.  I asked if they could provide the (already compromised) password so I could find the affected account in my password manager, they said they didn't actually have the password included in the breach (huh?), and recommended I change the password on my email account.  I don't see how changing the password on my email account will counter the compromise of an unknown account.

**What's the basis for recommending resetting my email password when an unknown account password is compromised?**

---

This is the entirety of the information in their alert:

[image: breach report]

Their response to my subsequent inquiry looked like a form letter and didn't answer my question, and included this recommendation:

> If you have any affiliation with the website listed in the alert details as the source of the data breach, you should change your account password for that website, and also any of your other passwords that are the same as that password.
>
> If you do not recognize the website listed in the alert details as the source of the breach, then you should change the password for your email account, and also any of your other passwords that are the same as that password.

Which is unhelpful because there is no website listed in the details.  When I asked why they recommend changing the password for my email account they did not respond.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most salient part:

> you should change your account password **for that website**, and also **any of your other passwords that are the same as that password**.

Many people are not security savvy. Some people reuse the same password across multiple accounts. Like both their email and bank accounts. This is what enables [credential stuffing attacks](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/bots/what-is-credential-stuffing/) to succeed. This is not saying that *you* are security naive. If the bank is sending this to everyone affected then they're reasoning that this situation applies to some amount of people involved. Remember that the credential dump included the email address associated with the password. The second attack to attempt would be checking that password against that email account.

I have to send out these notifications from time-to-time. I prefer adding some additional suggested steps:

1. Change your password for the affected service.
2. Choose a strong password (password strength advice goes here).
3. Do not use the same password across multiple services.
4. Use a password manager (suggestions go here).
5. Do not use your corporate email address for personal business.

Suggestions 2 and 3 go towards defeating credential stuffing. Suggestion 4 is meant to make suggestions 2 and 3 less painful.

Comment: How is that part salient when there is no "that website"?  How are they getting from "we have no information about where these credentials were used" to "you should reset the password for your email account"?  Is that connection justified?

If it's based on the assumption that users are using the same password for their email account as for every account they log in to using their email address, is it still justified after I let them know that I have thousands of passwords in my password manager so the odds of that being the one that's comprised seem rather low?

Answer (score 0):

> without any indication of where this email and password was used

Then the notification is worthless. My guess is that they did, in fact, indicate what account the email was used on or had explained more.

> they said they didn't actually have the password

That's normal. They have signed up for a service like [Have I Been Pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) that notifies when credentials have been included in a breach, but they do not store the passwords (for obvious reasons).

> recommended I change the password on my email account

Again, I think there is some miscommunication. No, changing the email account password is not the thing you need to do, you need to change the password on the account that was compromised.

I would look over the material provided by your bank to see if they have mentioned which account was compromised.

Comment: Actually, the recommendation to change the email password is derived from the idea that a lot of people are using their email passwords to protect other accounts. So it is suggested by default.

Comment: @KamilKurzynowski that makes zero sense. The recommendation would be to change the password everywhere you've used it, not just on an arbitrary service's account. And that's a very, very specific assumption.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; I added a screenshot so you can see that they did not indicate what account was compromised.

Comment: What's this "obvious" reason to not store compromised passwords?  If the notification included the password (or a part of it) it would not be worthless.

Comment: I did answer with "No, changing the email account password is not the thing you need to do, you need to change the password on the account that was compromised."

Comment: The obvious reason is that the bank does not want to be responsible for knowing your password, and neither does the service they signed up for

Comment: I unintentionally put different questions in the title and body, sorry for the confusion, I changed the title to match the body

Comment: @ShadSterling Can you then also include the wording of their recommendation? You are asking for ***their*** basis, but we can't guess at their motivations.

Comment: The password is already compromised, everyone knows it.  Treating it as if it isn't compromised just makes it harder for me to respond appropriately.

Comment: Who is asking you to treat the password as not compromised?

Comment: Their wording is in the quote I added with (& beneath) the screenshot

Comment: You said the obvious reason to hide a compromised password was to keep it unknown, but a compromised password is known

Comment: That's not what I said at all. You have made a leap of faulty logic.

Comment: Here's what's happened: they have signed up for a service. The service picked up on the ["COMB"](https://cybernews.com/news/largest-compilation-of-emails-and-passwords-leaked-free/) That data dump did not always include the service that the credentials were used on. So their automated system gave you what it had.

Comment: @ShadSterling So, there is no "basis" for the recommendation. It's a canned response. That makes your new edited question impossible to answer. We can only guess about their reasons. I'm sorry that the data you were given was unhelpful. My answer stands: you need to change the password on the compromised account.

Comment: @ShadSterling and at no point did they say to change your email password. That's another faulty leap in logic. So, the basis for your question is unfounded.

Comment: Not sure how you can read "you should change the password for your email account" as not saying to change my email password, but ok.

Comment: "and also any of your other passwords that are the same as that password" -- this is the important part and this is what Kamil was getting at. They are not saying "change your email password". They are offering the only thing that can suggest that could possibly help; change everything. And isn't the place where your credentials used shadsterling.com? And if that's true, despite the template nature of the email, in your case, isn't it *actually* your email account password?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the semantics here.   As others have said, password re-use is cripplingly common, so they've sent out a form letter advising you that a password associated with your account has been breached.  I don't see that the bank has a duty of care that stretches telling you that a password has been exposed to committing to telling you that a password has been exposed here, and by extension, only here.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @D0gfather the first line in the question: "One of the banks that provides identity theft monitoring to accountholders..." No semantics here. No duty of care. This is a secondary service.

Answer (score -2):

First check your email id in the website https://haveibeenpwned.com/ to determine whether your account with email id has been found in any of the breached website.

If yes, Please don't use the same password in any other accounts, you used for that particular breached website.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question asked. This is a recommendation for an alternate approach. Also, the last line isn't really useful if the password has already been reused.